# Does Read::read guarantee to append data and not overwrite any existing one?

Tags: rust

I'm working on an SMTP library that reads lines over the network using a buffered reader.

I want a nice, safe way to read data from the network, without depending on Rust internals to make sure the code works as expected. Specifically, I'm wondering if the [`Read` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html) guarantees that data read with [`Read::read`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) is appended to the buffer passed as an argument rather than overwriting the buffer entirely.

At the moment, [I use a `Range`](https://github.com/conradkleinespel/rustastic-smtp/blob/927937d84649706c447fc63359318bb6d0c8bb3c/src/common/stream.rs#L138) to make sure existing data is not overwritten without depending on Rust internals.

However, given that Rust [used to have](https://github.com/conradkleinespel/rustastic-smtp/blob/cd632f9db4b5bc5a9af28303362e96f1caa3131a/src/common/stream.rs#L131) a nice way to do what I want, I'm wondering if the current code can be improved, possibly removing the `unsafe` blocks too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not guarantee that:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let mut source1 = "hello, world!".as_bytes();
    let mut source2 = "moo".as_bytes();

    let mut dest = [0; 128];
    source1.read(&mut dest).unwrap();
    source2.read(&mut dest).unwrap();

    let s = str::from_utf8(&dest[..16]).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", s)
}
```

This prints

```
"moolo, world!\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}"
```

Specifically, it cannot do what you want, based purely on the type signature:

```
fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize>;
```

All that the `read` method has access to is your mutable slice - there's nowhere to store information like "how far in the buffer you are". Furthermore, you aren't allowed to "extend" a mutable slice with more elements - you are only allowed to mutate the values within the slice.

For your particular case, you may want to look at [`BufRead::read_until`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_until). Here's a barely-tested example:

```
use std::io::{BufRead,BufReader};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let source1 = "header 1\r\nheader 2\r\n".as_bytes();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(source1);

    let mut buf = vec![];
    buf.reserve(128); // Maybe more efficient?

    loop {
        match reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buf) {
            Ok(0) => break,
            Ok(_) => {},
            Err(_) => panic!("Handle errors"),
        }

        if buf.len() < 2 { continue }

        if buf[buf.len() - 2] == b'\r' {
            {
                let s = str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap();
                println!("Got a header {:?}", s);
            }
            buf.clear();
        }
    }
}
```